# An example of a compact abelian group that is not a torus

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, abelian-groups, topological-groups

It is known that a compact connected Abelian Lie group is a torus. Is it also true for arbitrary compact connected Abelian group (not necessary a Lie group)?

I was not able to come up with the example of a compact connected Abelian, which is not a torus. All the examples I know are in fact Lie groups (such as real or complex elliptic curves).

There is a structural theorem for locally compact group which states that every locally compact group is a direct sum of $\mathbb R^n$, discrete group and a compact group. Howewer, this theorem has no information about the compact part.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoid_(mathematics)

Comment: Also see [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/315214/).